# Why does `less` show "This account is not available" when run on a file from a root login shell?

Tags: sudo, less, nologin

This is not really a problem, just a peculiarity that I'd like to understand.

If I get a root shell with `sudo bash -l` and then run `less somefilename` I get less only showing:

> This account is currently not available.

(This isn't shown as an *error*, it's shown inside less as though it were the contents of the file.)

However if I use the same root shell from `sudo bash -l` and run `cat somefilename | less` then I see the actual contents of the file.

Also if I get a root shell with `sudo bash` and skip the `-l` and then run `less somefilename` it will show the file's contents.

Root's login is disabled; the `/etc/passwd` line is `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/sbin/nologin` so `sudo su -` doesn't work.

But, why should the `nologin` entry make any difference to running `less` on a file?  And why does it only make a difference if `less` is run directly on the file rather than also applying to less running on its stdin?  And, why does this only happen with a `bash -l` shell?

(This is on a CentOS 7 system.)

Comment: Simple repro (for those without root access): `SHELL=/usr/sbin/nologin LESSOPEN='cat %s' less /etc/issue`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because of `less`’s method of invoking commands specified in `LESSOPEN` or `LESSCLOSE`. If the `SHELL` environment variable is set, it uses its value as the shell to use to run them.

Thus in your scenario, since `LESSOPEN` is set (thanks to the use of `lesspipe`), `less` runs the equivalent of `"$SHELL" -c …`, and shows the result of that as the file contents (since that’s the expected behaviour with a `LESSOPEN` pipe). Since `SHELL` is `nologin`, you see that command’s output.

With a default `lesspipe` setup, the pipe isn’t used if `less` is itself receiving its input from a pipe, which explains that behaviour.

`SHELL` is only set by login shells. If you run `bash` without `-l`, `SHELL` keeps whatever value it had previously.

(In fact, since `less` uses `popen`, the command run is `sh -c "$SHELL" -c …`)

Comment: Without this insightful explanation, I would never have had the idea to set someone's `LESSOPEN`to `rm %s`, say,